# Regex - partial url

Tags: regex

I think I’m pretty close, I’m writing a regex for a partial url.

Please note: my examples show a maximum of two / however it could have else or more. Example /test/test/test.htm

It can accept a-z 0-9 -  and . if it has one of the file extensions referenced below. It can't start/end with a - or a . there must be a number or character before and after. Currently my regex is accepting strings which should be rejected

Accepted

```
/test/test.htm (this could be jpeg|jpg|gif|png|htm|html)
/test/test
/test/test-test.htm
/test/test-test
/test/test123.htm
/test/test123
```

Should be rejected (but passing)

```
/test/test.
/test/.hhh
/tes  t
/tes_t
/tes"t
/tes’t
/-test (cannot start with any thing else other than letters/numbers
```

Regex: `^\/.*?(\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|htm|html)|([^\.])[\w-]{1})$`

Comment: Any case that is missing?

Comment: I think Ive thought of everything

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong, I need to restrict it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most complete regex I could find. I've added a comment to others' regex, because they'd fail on `/test/test-` (which their regex would accept).

```
^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+))*(\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|html?))?$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/eZ4eS5/4).

[image: Regex explanation]

If you need to match consequent `-` as well (e.g. `/test--test`), you can use the following regex, as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/eZ4eS5/6).

```
^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+((?:-+|\/)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+))*(\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|html?))?$
```

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Not sure if that's a case OP needs to match, but I've added the regex for such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Can probably be optimized:

```
^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\d]+)+([a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|htm|html))?$
```

[Try it live here](https://regex101.com/r/kV3kI0/6)

- We first match pattern for folders like `/abd` with `\/[a-zA-Z0-9\d]+` multiple time, that also include filename
- Also allows filename to have a `-` in their name
- Then optionally match for extension

Comment: Sorry probably me being stupid. /tes’t shows as matching, would that pass or fail?

Comment: Oups, forgot the `$` to be more strict on the matching. Have a look at my last edit.

Comment: This will fail on `/test/test-` - which it'll match.

Comment: Edited by moving the extension parameter to include full filename.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`^(?:\/[a-z0-9](?:[^\/ _"’\n.-]|\.(?=(?:jpe?g|gif|png|html?)$)|\-(?!$))+)+$`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dY8fI2/4)

Explaining:

`^(?:                                    # from start
    \/[a-z0-9]                          # one slash and one letter or digit
    (?:                                 # one of:
        [^\/ _"’\n.-]                     # characters not in this list
      |                                 # OR
        \.(?=(?:jpe?g|gif|png|html?)$)    # one dot with the condition 
                                          # of being the extension dot 
                                          # at the end
      |                                 # OR
        \-(?!$)                           # one - not at the end
    )+                                  # at least one of them to many
)+$                                     # as there could be /folder/folder
                                          # as many matches till the end`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will fail on `/test/test-` - which it'll match.